# getBoundingClientRect gives incorrect x coordinate if flex-direction is set to row-reverse

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom, flexbox

I am using `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the `x` coordinate of elements on a page. I see a weird behaviour which I am not able to explain. If I get the `x` coordinate for the `div` with class `grid`, I get the value `8` which looks correct. On the other hand, if I get it for the `div` with text `11`, I get the value `7.984375`. Since this div is displayed first, because of `flex-direction: row-reverse`, I expect it to have `x` equal to `8`. To check if this has anything to do with `flex-direction`, I changed its value to `row` and then fetched the `x` coordinate of `div` with text `1` and I got `8` as expected.

Could someone please help me understand why does `flex-direction` cause this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Auto Layout</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: cadetblue;
    }
    .grid {
      width: 600px;
      height: 800px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      gap: 20px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .item {
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">1</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 200px">2</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; width: 300px">3</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 300px; width: 100px">4</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 100px">5</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; width: 200px">6</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 300px">7</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 300px">8</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 200px; width: 200px">9</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 100px; width: 200px">10</div>
    <div class="item" style="height: 300px; width: 200px">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug in chrome. Please file at crbug.com/new